# how to properly manage triggered errors in PHP4

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, php4

m maintaining a project, that has to be compatible through PHP 4.X to 5.2. The project as several errors wich are not very well handled.

What I want to do is redirect user to a "nice" error page, and log the error in the database. In order to keep track of the user, the file, and the error message. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");
/**
 *My function to handle errors
 */
function myErrorHandler( $errno , $errstr ,  $errfile="nofile" , $errline=0 , $errcontextArray=NULL ){
    session_start();
    if (!isset($errno)|!isset($errstr)) {
        exit(0);
    }
    if (!mysql_ping()) {
        require '../Connection/databaseinfo.php';
    }
    $id_user = $_SESSION['ident'];
    $errstr = GetSQLValueString($errstr, "text");
    $errfile = GetSQLValueString($errfile, "text");
    $errline = GetSQLValueString($errline, "int");
    $sql = "insert into error_history 
        (id_user, message, file, line)
        values ($id_user, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)";
    mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

//    header("location:error.php"); ---> I can't (see comment below)
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> window.location.href='error.php';</script>";//Redirection dégueulasse //TODO: trouver mieux
    return true;
}
```

Why not `header()`? Because the error can be triggered anywhere in a page, and thus, having the headers already sent.

Why not `header()` along with `obstart(), ob_flush()`? Because there are lot of pages already in production, and I can't modify them all.

My questions are:

1. Am I doing it wrong?
2. Is there a better way to handle the
   redirection?

Comment: Given your restrictions, I see no better way of doing that. You obviously can't be psychic and fail before the error, so the best you can do is to fail as early as possible. The other option is to finish loading the page with a big orange ERRORS WERE ENCOUNTERED banner enabled via CSS, or modified via the same sort of javascript, but that might be highly undefined if your page is database heavy.

Comment: May I ask what these errors actually are? I prefer to organise my code in such a way that any processing that may cause a bad enough error to require an abort is done before I output anything if at all possible (which I accept it isn't always), and you may be asking the wrong question (maybe the question should be "how can I prevent these errors from occurring in the first place?"). The above may be the best way, but I'd prefer to see what errors you might be handing with it before I gave an opinion either way on that front.

Comment: Thanks, I also wondered about a `meta refresh=0;url=error.php`. But I'm not sure.

Comment: @DaveRandom There are mostly empty form inputs and wrong `$_GET` parameters. As the project is big enough, some old pages were coded using, erm, Dreamwaver. So the code definetly lacks controls. I want this error-handling system to help me find what pages are the most impacted and debug them.

Comment: Fair enough, in that case I think you are probably going down the best route. Browsers can be buggy in the respect of properly handling `<meta>` redirects outside the `<head>` but the `<script>` approach will work pretty much everywhere every time these days.

Comment: Why not creating a .htaccess to force all php scripts calls to go first to a single one which could properly obstart() ? This is not very good for performances but it gives you the ability to control everything ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to handle fatal errors in php 5.2:

```
<?php
register_shutdown_function('shutdownFunction');
function shutDownFunction() {
    $error = error_get_last();
    if($error['type'] >= 1){
        mail('cc@cc.de', 'Error: XY',"Error msg:"."Server Error:".implode("\n", $error));
    }
}
?>
```